# error resolving localhost while running java servlets in eclipse's browser

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am new to java servlets. I have installed apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21.

When I run the project containing servlet in eclipse browser, sometimes I get the error-
**Error resolving 'localhost': Name or service not known.**

Other times the error is - 
**Error resolving 'localhost' : Temporary failure in name resolution.**

This project runs fine in my web browser.

Also, after I add `<servlet>...</servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>...<servlet-mapping>` in web.xml, I get the error - **Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.**

One more thing, I use Ubuntu operating system (if it has to do something with the question).

Please help. I googled for the solution but I am not able to resolve the error.

Comment: Can you provide some more details of the Error/Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the below to your `/etc/hosts` file.

`127.0.0.1             localhost`